Formsubmit.co reCAPTCHA either doesn't load at all or is extremely slow
I'm using Formsubmit.co to process contact forms. When reCAPTCHA is enabled, submitting the form results in about a minute of blank page before the reCAPTCHA displays (sometimes it never displays), followed by another 60 seconds of loading, then a message that my reCAPTCHA didn’t process. I've tried requesting support directly from formsubmit.co but no response.
I tested this in four different browsers with various but similar results. I've temporarily disabled reCAPTCHA so that my form is functional again, but I know this is not a long-term solution. Does anyone know why this is happening? Thanks!!
Here's my form code:
<form target="_blank" action="https://formsubmit.co/someone@domain.com" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="_cc" value="someone@domain.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="_subject" value="New Evapor Contact Form Message">
    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Full Name" required>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="company" class="form-control" placeholder="Company Name" required>
    <br>
    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" required>
    <br>
    <input type="tel" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" required>
    <br>
    <textarea placeholder="Your Message" class="form-control" name="message" rows="10" required></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="_captcha" value="false">
    <input type="hidden" name="_next" target="_self" value="https://evapor.com/thankyou.html">
    <button type="submit" class="button_large">Send</button>

</form>


Not sure what anyone can do to help you here.  It appears that the recaptcha feature of formsubmit.co is problematic.  Since the code you provided disables that feature, this isn't a programming issue.  I would suggest if you want to assist in trying to debug the problem, that you should use your browser developer tools, to debug what is happening at the point you submit the form.  The network tab is a good place to start.
